# Why is the background not loading?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840,2160))
running = True
pygame.display.set_caption("GermanBall")
bg = pygame.image.load("Tan.jpg")
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()
```

i need to know why this doesnt work

i tried changing the resolution of the image and the screen but to no avail, the image and screen are of same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an indentation problem on the two last lines. The `blit` and the `update` are outside the `while` loop:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840,2160))
running = True
pygame.display.set_caption("GermanBall")
bg = pygame.image.load("Tan.jpg")
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))  # <- HERE
    pygame.display.update()  # <- HERE
```